# I want to put a mp4 video for the background, however it doesn't appear and it is black when I embed it

Tags: html, css

When I write this, nothing appears and when I just embed the video, a blank video player is there.

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Live Giveaway</h1>

    <video autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video2.ogg" type="video/ogg">

    </video>

</div>
```

Comment: Please include your CSS

Answer (score 0):

in the css custom, for example:

```
<video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <!--<source src="video2.ogg" type="video/ogg"> here is for  videos on .ogg but not all of browsers support all the video files, try only use .mp4--> 
</video>
```

then in css:

```css
video{ 
     width: 100%; /* if you want that the video is full on the left to the right */ 
     position: fixed; /* is the best */
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;

     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     z-index: -1; /* this one is for the video, that will always be on the bottom */
}
```

Comment: is it the problem with my mp4? because it is still blank

Comment: Maybe, try to put another mp4 video